# Attempt to ReadAsync from SerialDevice silently crashes app

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I have a task that is running continuously reading from a serial port. I don't see any outward reason that this wouldn't work, but I don't discount that I could be missing something obvious.

```cs
if (serialPort != null)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer inputBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1024);
        Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer resultBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1024);
        using (var childCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token))
        {
            var t = serialPort.InputStream.ReadAsync(inputBuffer, inputBuffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.Partial).AsTask(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            resultBuffer = (Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer)await t;
            if (resultBuffer.Length > 0)
            {
                LogDebug(string.Format("Read {0} bytes", resultBuffer.Length));
                DataReader dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(resultBuffer);
                string resultString = dataReader.ReadString(resultBuffer.Length);
                OnDataReceived(new DataReceiptEventArgs { Data = resultString });
            }
        }
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

The result from this is that it reads correctly on the first iteration, but `ReadAsync` does not seem to handle no data on the stream gracefully when the next iteration happens and all the data has already been read. I would like the behavior to be that task did not return until data was available. At the very least, I would expect an exception, so I might be able to catch that the read failed.

Instead, the debugger logs a message that my app 'has exited with code -1073741811 (0xc000000d).' which is `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

What am I doing wrong? Or will this really never work?

#### Edit:

This code produces the same error:

```
if (serialPort != null)
{
    dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
    LogDebug("Listening...");
    while (true)
    {
        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;
        ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        using (var childCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token))
        {
            UInt32 bytesRead = 0;
            bytesRead = await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(childCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                LogDebug(string.Format("Read {0} bytes", bytesRead));
                string resultString = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                OnDataReceived(new DataReceiptEventArgs { Data = resultString });
            }
        }
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

As well as having a read thread going, I also was writing using a `DataWriter`. But my write method would dispose of the `DataWriter` on every write. Instead, I now have that declared as a private member of my serial class, and I instantiate the `DataWriter` upon connection and dispose of it in my close method.

This seems to keep communication going.

Not sure why this happens though, any explanations are welcome.